# Why do I get the specified value is out of range when accessing the shape object?

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I wrote this function to loop through powerpoint slides in a vba macro. I wanted it to then loop through the shapes on each slide and set the text to user defined defaults.

I got this working and now for some reason after tidying up it stopped working. I get Run-time-error '-2147024809 (80070057) The specified value is out of range.

When I debug it works up to a certain slide. In my case it's a test slide with 5 objects of different types with text in. There is a group.

Despite doing some study and training this one has me stumped. Would really appreciate some help. I'm sure it's a simple solution but I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

```
Sub FontDefaultAllSlidesBody()
'Sets the text for all shapes on all slides in active presentation

'Set variables for functions
    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oSls As Slides
    Set oSls = ActivePresentation.Slides

'Set our default font settings
    For Each oSl In oSls
        For i = 1 To oSl.Shapes.Count
            With oSl.Shapes(i).TextFrame.TextRange.Font
                .Size = 16
                .Bold = msoFalse
                .Italic = msoFalse
                .Underline = msoFalse
                .Color = msoThemeColorAccent1
                .Name = "+mn-lt"
            End With
        Next i
     Next oSl
End Sub
```

Comment: So if I get what you're writing, there is a group of shapes in slide 5 and that's where the code crashes?

Comment: Hey Jon. Thanks for the reply. Your question prompted me to check exactly where and and I deleted the slide to see if it was that slide. It wasn't. It's a slide I have used zoom slide objects on. I guess I can use if statements to create logic to account for those.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably be enough to solve the problem. It tests each shape to see if it *can* contain text and if so, if it *does* contain text and only then does it try to *modify* the text.

I've also changed the loop a bit to use a Shape object; cuts out a lot of typing and (I think) makes it clearer what you're dealing with.

```
Sub FontDefaultAllSlidesBody()
'Sets the text for all shapes on all slides in active presentation

'Set variables for functions
    Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oSls As Slides
' This will make it easier to read:
    Dim oSh as Shape
    Set oSls = ActivePresentation.Slides

'Set our default font settings
    For Each oSl In oSls
        For Each oSh in oSl.Shapes
          ' Add this to keep it from touching shapes that 
          ' can't contain text
          If oSh.HasTextFrame Then
            ' And skip shapes that have no text
            If oSh.TextFrame.HasText Then
              With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange.Font
                .Size = 16
                .Bold = msoFalse
                .Italic = msoFalse
                .Underline = msoFalse
                .Color = msoThemeColorAccent1
                .Name = "+mn-lt"
              End With
            End If ' HasText
          End If ' HasTextFrame
        Next  ' Shape
     Next oSl
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Steve thank you. Was just having a go at testing HastText and TextFrame. Clears it up for me. I did try using the cleaner method with the shape object but it ignores groups. The loop I used seemed to do it for all shapes including groups without needing to write logic for it.

Comment: Interesting; haven't got time to try that out just now, but plenty of room on the Infinite Backburner.